# Is freedom of the press covered under the 14th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution?

Tags: united-states, constitution, freedom-of-speech, fourteenth-amendment

The First Amendment reads:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press, or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

As written, the 1st Amendment restriction covers Congress and not state legislatures. It also does not define the freedoms; instead, it restricts the federal government from abridging certain rights.

Some argue that this was a mistake and that the 14th Amendment extended protection of all these freedoms to state government.   But the 14th Amendment makes no explicit mention of freedom of the press.   **Are there authoritative sources that hold that the 14th Amendment applies to freedom of the press?**  I'm thinking about things like court cases...   Citations in any answers, please.

After evaluating historical quotes that suggest the wording of the 1st Amendment was no mere mistake, I ask the question. It seems probable the founding fathers expected the First Amendment to apply exclusively to the Federal government, particularly about freedom of the press.

For example:

> *"The States... retain to themselves the right of judging how far the licentiousness of speech and of the press may be abridged without lessening their useful freedom, and how far those abuses which cannot be separated from their use should be tolerated rather than the use be destroyed."* --Thomas Jefferson: Draft of Kentucky Resolutions, 1798. ME 17:381

and

> *"The power to [restrain slander] is fully possessed by the several State Legislatures. It was reserved to them, and was denied to the General Government, by the Constitution, according to our construction of it. While we deny that Congress have a right to control the freedom of the press, we have ever asserted the right of the States, and their exclusive right, to do so. They have accordingly all of them made provisions for punishing slander which those who have time and inclination resort to for the vindication of their characters. In general, the state laws appear to have made the presses responsible for slander as far as is consistent with their useful freedom. In those states where they do not admit even the truth of allegations to protect the printer they have gone too far."* --Thomas Jefferson to Abigail Adams, 1804. ME 11:51

Comment: "The press" is not a special group.  The press are merely just people who report things.  Why would there be a special provision for those people?  They, as ordinary people, have 1st amendment protection.  The 14th says that no state can limit guaranteed rights, free speech included.

Comment: @ACPilot, I would tend to disagree.   The key distinction I think between the people and the media becomes the matter of profit motivation.

Comment: Haha.  I agree!  But that does not make them a special class of "free speakers."  They are still like all other normal people, it's just their job to transmit accurate context and  information to their customers (which appears to be quite difficult for many of them).  I think we agree that being a "journalist" does not elevate a person to a special status.  Free speech is free speech, no special or imaginary qualifiers needed.

Comment: My understanding is that "freedom of the press" actually refers to the device, more broadly it guarantees that not only is there a right to speech but also a right to use technological means to disseminate and propagate that speech.

Comment: Even devices that the founders could never have imagined?

Comment: @acpilot in practice bring a member of the press does give some special privileges.  One example is not being subject to curfews during the protests/ riots.  And if they are arrested during them they are almost always quickly released without charges.

Comment: Almost everyone is released without charges!  There are sometimes some special permissions granted to press but they have no extra rights.  They're not a protected class, nor should they be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern jurisprudence on this issue is that the entire First Amendment is incorporated into the Fourteenth Amendment.  Based on some research [*Near v. Minnesota*](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/283/697/#707) seems to be the seminal case incorporating freedom of the press.  From the opinion:

> 2. Liberty of the press is within the liberty safeguarded by the due process clause of the Fourteenth Amendment from invasion by state action.

> This statute, for the suppression as a public nuisance of a newspaper or periodical, is unusual, if not unique, and raises questions of grave importance transcending the local interests involved in the particular action. It is no longer open to doubt that the liberty of the press, and of speech, is within the liberty safeguarded by the due process clause of the Fourteenth Amendment from invasion by state action.

Comment: Very relevant, thank you.   I note however that it says "Liberty of the press is not an absolute right, and the State may punish its abuse. P. 283 U. S. 708."   The ruling seems to be one about due process and the prior restrain imposed by contempt provisions in the law.   I'll read further.

Comment: @Burt_Harris That's true of freedom of speech as well, states and the federal government can criminalize and allow civil remedy for some forms of speech like defamation but prior restraint is usually unconstitutional.  As I understood your question it was just whether or not freedom of the press is incorporated like freedom of speech is.

Comment: @Burt_Harris The federal government is only more restricted than states in that there are theoretically fewer areas of law they are allowed to legislate in, so most normal limitations on speech (e.g. threats) are wholly within the realm of state legislature jurisdiction (or left to the federal territories to regulate themselves).  There are some federal speech laws though, e.g. [broadcasting obscene language over a radio](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1464).

Comment: I agree in general.   That said, the example you give of threats seems an open question in federal law.   In Elonis v. US, 18 U.S.C. § 875(c) was challenged on 1st amendment (and other) grounds.   While the SCOTUS overturned the conviction on other grounds, it left the 1st amendment argument unresolved.

Comment: I wonder if the federal obscenity provisions in 18 USC §§1464-1468 have faced 1st amendment challenges.   But that's really not the point of my question.

Comment: Brian. I would suggest you improve your answer by clarifying that Near v. Minn. dealt with due process under the 14th more than pure 1st amendment freedom of the press.   The prior restraint of temporary injunction issued (before evidence was heard in court) is different from a court's final order punishing some past abuse.

Comment: @Burt_Harris I'm not sure I understand your contention.  From what I can tell (which could be wrong), *Near* was the first SCOTUS case to state explicitly that the 14th Amendment incorporates freedom of the press.  It wasn't a question at issue because all parties and the Court agreed on that matter of law even if it didn't have a direct precedent.

Comment: @Burt_Harris RE *Elonis* - I'd suggest asking on law.se if you want a more detailed explanation of how that case could impact the existing law.  Same with a question about obscenity.

Comment: @Burt_Harris For what it's worth, *all* applications of the Bill of Rights to the states turn on due process under the 14th Amendment. That's the mechanism the courts use, for reasons that presumably made sense to someone at some point. Even if the case has nothing to do with procedures, courts treat a law that violates "fundamental rights" (which is not quite identical to violating the Bill of Rights but is closely related) as a due process violation.

Comment: No need to ask lawyer to understand the distinction between prior restraint and post-judgment enforcement of consequences of abusing a limited right.   The [prior restraint doctrine](https://bit.ly/3xOzyxg) existed far before either the 1st or 14th Amendments, dating back to the 15th century.   It was a subject of debate during the writing of the 1st, and was by no means new when the 14th Amendment was adopted.

Comment: @Burt_Harris If it is more comfortable to think about it this way, the 14th Amendment incorporation doctrine is a legal fiction by which the court evaded the fact that the Bill of Rights only applies to the federal government. Even though the 14th Amendment doctrinally is what made it so, incorporation didn't really start to happen in earnest 'til the 1910s, about half a century later. The Privileges and Immunities Clause would have been a more natural approach but the Slaughterhouse cases (motivated by pro Jim Crow SCOTUS justices at the time) and other prior case law precluded that solution.

Comment: @ohwilleke, it seems to me that due process applies to courts (and pseudo-judicial processes in executive branch agencies), not to legislatures.   If a State legislature passed a law allowing a district court to impose a $100 fine for printing the word "fnord" in a sentence, would the law itself fall under due process?

Comment: @Burt_Harris The Court has held that the incorporated provisions of the Bill of Rights are necessary to have a society in which due process in our system of government can prevail. It is not due process in the narrow procedural sense.

Comment: @ohwilleke, OK, but this particular legal fiction makes me particularly uncomfortable, and I'm having a hard time expressing why.  I guess I'm more comfortable with States being able to punish the "fnords", than the federal government having that power.